# Azure AD RBAC User.IsInRole throws Trust Relationship error when not on domain

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I've written a c# app that uses Azure AD. Below is my Startup.Auth.cs file. Everything works fine when I am connected to the domain. However, when I use `User.IsInRole` when not on domain I get a Trust Relationship error. What could be the cause?

**Additionally:** Using the `[Authorize(Roles="MyRole")]` WORKS!
The exact error is: `The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.`

```
// Startup.Auth.cs
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];

    string authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true, // For Single-Tenant App.
                    RoleClaimType = "roles" // Grab roles when user authenticates.
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }

            });
        // This makes any middleware defined above this line run before the Authorization rule is applied in web.config
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Here is an example of what I was doing in my controller:

```
var entitiesToDisplay = db.myEntities
     .where(x => x.RequiredRole == string.empty || User.IsInRole(x.RequiredRole);
```

I changed this to:

```
IEnumerable<Entities> entitiesToDisplay;
if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    entitiesToDisplay = db.myEntities
     .where(x => x.RequiredRole == string.empty || User.IsInRole(x.RequiredRole);
}
else {
    entitiesToDisplay = new List();
}
```

Ultimately, it turns out that `User.IsInRole` throws the exception when `Request.IsAuthenticated` i not true. Checking `Request.IsAuthenticated` resolved my issue.